# How to command --block-size=512 and -b together in unix?

Tags: unix, cygwin

I am studying Unix at school now, and I am stuck on a question here.

I am trying to figure out what is the cluster count allocation when cluster size is 512 , 1024, 4096 in bytes.

so i tried to use `du --block-size=512` and `-b` together, but it never worked together(I tried in many different ways)

How can i command it to get cluster count in bytes??

Also, I need to figure out what's the internal fragmentation and what is unused numbers of bytes.

Can anyone teach me how to do it? I am using Cygwin

Thanks!

```
du -b --block-size=512
```

expected to see roughly numbers of 18,294,470.5

Comment: According to the man page (`man du`), the `-b` flag is a short form of `--block-size=1`. Hence specifying both `-b` and `--block-size` produces a contradiction and it can't work.